# Cut and Paste string values to next input after tab character using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how can I achieve, using javascript/jquery, splitting a string as listed below -

```
abc543567   abc543678   abc223416   abc634567
```

into four inputs, so that each group can be moved into a separate input. Basically, when I copy this string into the first input, the first group can remain in the first input, the second to be moved in the second input, and so on. In the example, between the groups, I used as separator the tab characters. Here is the html for the inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/2sb6ggz0/

Update of HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form name="form1" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input1" name="query" placeholder="Input 1" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form name="form2" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input2" name="query" placeholder="Input 2" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td> 
    <td>
        <form name="form3" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input3" name="query" placeholder="Input 3" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>                    
        <form name="form4" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input4" name="query" placeholder="Input 4" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way top achieve this?

Comment: you want to make it like serial key?` ABC-DEV-322` splitted to 3 inputs?

Comment: This wasn't my premise, however, yes, it can be taken as a serial key input. It would be 4 inputs.

Comment: im working on it :) hold on

Comment: Are the sections ALWAYS in the format of 9 alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @ freefaller - No, the sections would be variable in length

Comment: Then you should have made that clear, as your examples are all the same format. And notifications won't work with a space between the @ and the username. It's only chance that I've seen your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2sb6ggz0/6/

```
function split(sep, clazz) {

    var items = $(clazz);

    items.each(function (i) {

        $(this).on("paste", function () {
            var me = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                var splitted = me.val().split(sep);
                items.each(function (i) {
                    $(this).val(splitted[i]);
                });
            }, 1);
        });
    })
};    
split("-", ".query-input")
```

Comment: while you are pasting something in an input, the browser needs a millisecond to update the val. try it yourself, when you remove the timeout, the val would not be filled yet :)

Comment: if this wasn't enough, feel free to comment, and i will update it for your wishes, when im back from launch ;)

Comment: @ Mephiztopheles - Thanks! It works when I have dashes "-" as separators, however, can this be adjusted to tab separators?

Comment: shoud be `\t` as regex  
`split(/\t/, ".query-input")` or `split(new RegExp("\t"), ".query-input")` - yes, checked it

Comment: @ Mephiztopheles - for some reason the code doesn't work, is there a syntax error or something in the above mentioned code?

Comment: `split(/\t/, ".query-input")` - which browser? - https://jsfiddle.net/2sb6ggz0/11/

Comment: @ Mephiztopheles - Never mind, sorry, I just pasted the wrong set of characters, without tab character. Thanks!

Comment: @ Mephiztopheles - I just replaced the \t with \s+ to make sure that it will work with white spaces too. Thanks!

Comment: @ Mephiztopheles I came back for a question. If I want to apply this function on different classes, how do I implement the if statement (I have a checkbox, and if checked, run function for class, if not, for a different class)? It doesn't want to work with a simple if statement. Here's an update https://jsfiddle.net/2sb6ggz0/13/

Comment: Well ... for now, i have 2 methods for you: https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/2sb6ggz0/14/

Comment: Sorry, I made the html more clear now, for what I would exactly need here: https://jsfiddle.net/2sb6ggz0/16/ Basically, if only checkbox-1 is checked, only first two inputs split, if only checkbox-2 is checked, only last two inputs split. if both of them checked, all inputs split, if none is checked, no inputs split. I thought I can add more than one class to an input, and with a conditional statement change the split class, however doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use this : https://jsfiddle.net/2sb6ggz0/17/ ;)  
PS.: When you need some cool stuff : http://code.mephiztopheles.wtf/  
It may take a while to load, due to loading data from github.  Also check http://mephiztopheles.wtf/ for some demonstration (unfortunetly not all)

Comment: Thanks, however it does not work. Only when both checked it splits the 3 values between the inputs. If only one checked, it splits the values randomly. The expected result: none checked, does not split; both checked: splits the three values; only first checked:  a into input1, b into input2, when pasting into input3 does not split and preserves a b c in input 3. Only second checked: splits a into input2, b into input3, c nowhere, and when pasting into input1, does not split values. Is there any solution, even modified html, addded classes, etc so that the result would be as aforementioned?

Comment: That would take a while, because i / you need to switch for checkbox states. also you need to save the checkbox-ids into variables and add the state to that id. With your newest information, you should be ablo to rework the code to get your expected result. just get in mind as test, what extact switch cases you have and write it down in js. modifying your html is not necessary in my opinion. when pasting in input 3, you can implement by adding a new class to this input ... like "ignote-paste" or something and check that on paste-event or do the other way round and add a new class to the others

Comment: I made 3 split functions, with different names, this works for me for now. It is not as neat as some would expect, but it works for now. Take a look if you want https://jsfiddle.net/2sb6ggz0/18/ Thanks for your prompt responses and your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can respond to the `paste` event by detecting what's in the first input and, if appropriate, moving bits of it to the other three *(see comments)*:

```js
// Text to paste: abc543567   abc543678   abc223416   abc634567
// Hook "paste" on the first input
$("#input1").on("paste", function() {
  // Remember the input and wait a second so the paste gets filled in
  var input = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    // See if it matches our format
    var n;
    var value = input.value;
    var m = /^[ \t]*([\w\d]{9})[ \t]+([\w\d]{9})[ \t]+([\w\d]{9})[ \t]+([\w\d]{9})[ \t]*$/.exec(value);
    if (m) {
      // It does, save the values to the other fields
      for (n = 1; n <= 4; ++n) {
        $("#input" + n).val(m[n]);
      }
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form name="form1" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input1" name="query" placeholder="Input 1" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form name="form2" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input2" name="query" placeholder="Input 2" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td> 
    <td>
        <form name="form3" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input3" name="query" placeholder="Input 3" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>                    
        <form name="form4" action="#" method="get" target="">
            <input id="input4" name="query" placeholder="Input 4" type="search" size="20">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You'll want to adjust the regular expression to accept the correct format; I just told it to allow exactly 9 "word" characters and digits in four groups, separated by one or more tabs or spaces.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder - Sorry, I just pasted the fiddle. I have updated my question with the html code

Comment: @DantèsCristo: I've updated the answer, but again, we're talking trivial selector changes here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution.

```
$("input[name=query]").on("paste", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var id = $this.attr("id"), no = parseInt(id.substr(5)),
            groups = $this.val().split(/\s+/);
        if (groups) {
            var i = 0;
            while (no <= 4 && i < groups.length) {
                $("#input" + no).val(groups[i]);
                ++no;
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/rn9ydtop/

Answer (score -1):

You can use an event listener to skip to the next box when you have typed in a certain number of characters.

In jQuery it would be something like

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.target.val().length === 9) {
        $(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
    }
})
```

Comment: the strings would need to be copied and pasted, not typed in the inputs.