# Javascript textbox value append and focus

Tags: javascript

I have four text box of max lenght 4 
User can enter ABC5 12T4 45R7 78RT however 
nd if user copy complete 16 digit i.e ABC512T445R778RT and paste in first text box remaining text should get added in 2nd, 3rd and fourth text box

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164861/cut-and-paste-string-values-to-next-input-after-tab-character-using-javascript-j

Answer (score 0):

Provided such html code:

```
<input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text">
```

You can try something like this:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var inputsArray = [].slice.call(inputs);

inputsArray.forEach(bindInputEvent);

function bindInputEvent(node) {
    node.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        var startingField = inputsArray.indexOf(e.target);
        if (e.target.value.length > 4) {
            fillFields(this.value, startingField);
        }
    })
};

function fillFields(code, startingField) {
    inputsArray.slice(startingField).forEach(function (item, iter) {
        item.value = code.slice(iter * 4, iter * 4 + 4);
    });
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jcphevg4/

**Edit:**

The code above will work with IE>8. If you need to support legacy browsers (Internet Explorer 8 and older), I'd relly encourage you to use jQuery. The code will look like this:

```js
var inputs = $('.code-input');
$(function () {
    inputs.on('input', function () {
        var startingField = $(this).prevAll('.code-input').length;
        if (this.value.length > 4) {
            fillFields(this.value, startingField);
        }
    });
});

function fillFields(code, startingField) {
    inputs.slice(startingField).each(function (iter) {
        this.value = code.slice(iter * 4, iter * 4 + 4);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="code-input">
<input type="text" class="code-input">
<input type="text" class="code-input">
<input type="text" class="code-input">
```

Comment: if i input ABC512T445R778RT

then the output comes as 
ABC5 BC51 C512 512T

everytime the last 3 digit from prev textbox is copied in new text box
which is wrong i Need Output as ABC5 12T4 45R7 78RT

Comment: @NitinDivate oh, yes, you're right - I had a small bug in this slicing algorithm ;) It's fixed now.

Comment: thanks Tomek Sułkowski 
yes your function works for first text box 
ABC512T445R778RT is added as ABC5 12T4 45R7 78RT
however if i do the same for 2nd, 3rd and 4th text box it doesn't work
requirement is on any text box if i paste it should work
on second text box 12T445R778RT then it should 12T4 45R7 78RT

however this seems to be jsquery do you have equivalent javascript

Comment: @NitinDivate  Oh man, you are _demanding_ :D Ok, I have written it in plain JavaScript, for the purists souls ;) I've also taken into account this requirement about pasting in other fields. If you need another modifications I'm sure you'll be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for demanding :) but this one is my last question
if i have input type like below in my form
<input type="text" id="ab">
<input type="text" id="id">

<input type="text" id="id1">
<input type="text" id="id2">
<input type="text" id="id3">
<input type="text" id="id4">

how can i restrict the function only for id1,id2,id3 and id4

Comment: No problem. Actually, you've quite got it: if you want to join several independent selectors (like "give me those thigs, those, and this one), you have to use a comma, and if you target specific `id` you have to put `#` before its value. So you change the first line to: `var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#id1, #id2, #id3, #id4');`

Comment: … but I think it would be cleaner if you add some class to those four inputs (let't say `<input … class="code-input" />`) and then use a class selector: `var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.code-input');` (mind the dot before the class name)

Comment: sorry Tomek i am new to javascript so asking too much
My application doesn't support > IE8
document.querySelectorAll and inputsArray.forEach is not working 
in my application

so instead of document.querySelectorAll i have used 
var inputs = new Array(4);
inputs[0] = document.getElementById("id1");
inputs[1] = document.getElementById("id2");
inputs[2] = document.getElementById("id3");
inputs[3] = document.getElementById("id4");

can you please help me with the code how to call using normal for loop 
instead of foreach

Comment: To be honest I even started writing the solution that supports older IE but it really is too convoluted, especially if you are new to it. You have to select items, iterate over them, bind events, etc, etc, in whole other way…  If you really have to support legacy Intertet Explorer I'd go with jQuery - it does smooth a lot of things up. I'll update my answer with the jQuery version. **It's much simpler**.

Comment: I agree with you Tomek jquery is much simpler but jquery is not an Option only JavaScript :(

Comment: Sorry man, I honestly can't spent more time on this issue.. :/

Answer (score 0):

You may try using blur event:

```js
var codes;
$(function() {
  codes = $('input.code'); // cache all inputs
  codes.eq(0).on('change', splitCode); // first textbox input handler
  codes.on('change', validateCode); // reset for restricting max 4 characters
});

var validateCode = function() { // restricting max 4 characters
  this.value = this.value.slice(0, 4).toUpperCase();
};

var splitCode = function() {
  var txt = this.value.toUpperCase();
  if(16 > txt.length) { // less than 16, not sufficient to fill the reset
    this.value = txt.slice(0, 4);
    return;
  }
  $.each(codes, function(i){
    this.value = txt.slice(i*4, (i + 1)* 4);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class='code' />
<input type="text" class='code' />
<input type="text" class='code' />
<input type="text" class='code' />
```