# HTML Paste Split Text Into Different Form Input Fields?

Tags: html, formatting

I wanna make an address possible to copy and paste into different input fields on a website that I don't have control over. I thought it was possible to just use the HTML tab code (`&ensp;`, `&emsp;` and `&nbsp;`) for that but it didn't work.

So I want for example this text:

```
Firstname Lastname 
Street 4A
123 45 City
```

to be able to be copied and then pasted into input fields like this:

```
[ Firstname ] [ Lastname ]
[ Street 4A ]
[ 123 45 ] [ City ]
```

Is it possible? It doesn't need to be done with a copy link, I'm just thinking a regular copy paste with the keys on the keyboard.

Comment: You have no control on the target page? So how you want to override the default paste event?

Comment: I thought that tabs in the code would make it tab at the target page too so if I have a tab code after first and lastname then it would tab and move the cursor to the next field in the form even at the target page. I just remember it worked like that a lot of years ago when I did it. But maybe I remember it wrong or the standards has changed.

Comment: If you has control on the target page this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164861/cut-and-paste-string-values-to-next-input-after-tab-character-using-javascript-j . However if you are about doing a large data entry, there is a trick to do that. You can overrdie copying a whole script block into clipboard when you copy from the source and put the data within the script. Then paste the whole script in the address bar and shift data to the target inputs using ID or name.

Comment: this is a sample of what I mean in previous comment which should be copied in the clipboard: `javascript:$('#firstname').val(firstname)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not possible if I don't have control over the target page.